# How to remove top margin above \tableofcontents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

My contents page would fit on one side, if LateX wouldn't force an automatic whitespace block on top of the table of contents.

Is there any way to remove this block and have `\tableofcontents` start at the top of the page?

Comment: hmm - could you provide a minimal working example, and explain what you have already tried, for example `\vspace*{-5cm}` or something else?

Comment: @epsilon'εⳆ2'halbe yes I tried \vspace*{-5cm} but it didn't work. It only gave me a blank page and the same design as the original (with the big margin) on the following page.

Comment: please include such information, what you tried and it's effects in your question. Additionally an example would help - you can add text with `\usepackage{lipsum}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the standard document classes (like [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls)), `\tableofcontents` is set as a `\chapter*`:

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

So, it would be possible to temporarily modify the chapter heading macro to not insert as much vertical space. Here's a look at the `\chapter*` heading macro `\@makeschapterhead`:

```
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

Note the insertion of vertical space (`\vspace*{50\p@}`) before setting the heading. So, we can temporarily redefine this macro to not insert the vertical space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
% Redefine the \chapter* header macro to remove vertical space
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}% Remove the vertical space
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents
\endgroup
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

The grouping of the redefinition makes it local. Therefore, all modifications are restored after `\endgroup`.

Since the `\chapter*` header macro only uses `\vspace*{..}` to insert the gap between the text block and chapter header, you could also redefine `\vspace` to gobble the two arguments (`*` and `{50\p@}`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\vspace}[2]{}% Gobble 2 arguments after \vspace
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
\chapter{A chapter}\section{A section}\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

The [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) highlights the text block boundary (in addition to other elements) and is therefore only used in this example to showcase the vertical alignment of the table of contents. It is not needed in your final document.

---

Perhaps a cleaner approach would be to use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch `\@makeschapterhead`. This would also allow you to separate document structure from content (making what resides in the `document` environment only relate to the content). Add the following to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\begingroup%
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}% <cmd>
    {\vspace*{50\p@}}% <search>
    {}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
  \oldtableofcontents%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother
```

The above does a local search-and-replace within `\@makeschapterhead` (replacing `\vspace*{50\p@}` with nothing, before calling the regular table of contents. The redefinition (search-and-replace) is localized within the scope of the group.

Comment: Werner, I'm surprised this question, and your answer, hasn't got more attention, as I would imagine you helped a lot of people in this situation. I just Googled the issue, and found your solution, and without a tweak, it worked.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, wonderful answer. I used this for my thesis and added a `\hrule` to keep consistency with other chapter headings.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a `tocloft` way that has not been mentioned so far:

`tocloft` provides the `\cftbeforeXtitleskip` and `\cftafterXtitleskip` lengths, where `X` stands for `toc`, `lof` or `lot`, depending on the specific needs.

The advantage of using `tocloft` is that it hides the specific class settings, however, don't use `tocloft` with a KOMA class -- that's not recommended.

The values in the given example are just arbitrary!

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Default values are 50pt before title and 40pt after:
http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/contents/tocloft.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

`\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace{-1cm} \hfill\bfseries\LARGE TABLE OF CONTENTS \hfill \vspace{0.2cm}}`

The values inside the 1st/2nd `\vspace{}` control the vertical spaces before/after 'TABLE OF CONTENTS'.

Remember to put the command inside `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`.