# How eliminate a blank page after Table of Contents

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, positioning, indexing, sections-paragraphs

I have a problem for making the table of contents in latex.

1. Latex is making a **blank** page after the table of contents how to eliminate it?
2. I want to reduce the font of the word **Contents** by setting the font Large
3. I want to move the Content on the top of the page
4. In the actual table of content the `\subsubsection` do not appear in the table of content
5. I have four latex files. Do you suggest to join all the files in one latex or it would be better to keep them separate? I also have different style of numbering pages for the first 4 pages with roman letter instead the rest of the thesis is in arabic letter.

I just put the preamble and the latex option for the table of content

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=238mm, left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
 %  \usepackage[overload]{empheq}

 \usepackage{empheq, nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\usepackage{cases}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}  

%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe} 

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{lineno}
%\linenumbers
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.8} 
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{cases}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Subscripts}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{C}{Superscripts}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{D}{Acronyms{}}}}}%
]}

 % This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\Large}
%\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\section{Hello}
..
\subsection{Hello 1.1}
..
\subsubsection{Hello1.1.1}


..
\section{Road}
..
\section{Road}
..
\section{Road}

...
\end{document}}
```

[image]

Comment: You want to achieve a lot of things in one question ;-) Please reduce your document to the absolute minimum that shows the feature, i.e. kick out unnecessary packages, especially some packages are loaded twice and **fontspec** and **inputenc** is completely useless to load both!

Comment: Sorry, this preamble is a total mess. Use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` to make the `\subsubsection`s to show up in the ToC!

Comment: It's also not really useful to post an example that does not show the blank page at all since the 'document' does have one page only :-(

Comment: The shifting of `Contents` title upwards is explained in the answers to this question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62125/how-to-remove-top-margin-above-tableofcontents/311055#311055

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: I kicked some (but not all) packages out that are not related to the problem.

- I could not reproduce the blank page issue
- The ToC title can be shifted upwards with `\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0pt}`
  for example (this requires `tocloft` package)
- The ToC title font size (and other features) can be set with

  `\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\bfseries\Large}`

  which  requires `tocloft` as well
- `subsubsection`s do not appear by default in a ToC since the the `tocdepth` counter has a default value of `2`, i.e. only down to `subsections` will make it to the ToC. Use a value of `3` or larger.

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=238mm, left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%  Where is this used?

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe} 


%\linenumbers
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.8} 
\setlength{\parindent}{4em} %Sure???

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Subscripts}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{C}{Superscripts}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{D}{Acronyms{}}}}}%
]}

 % This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\Large}
%\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\bfseries\Large} % Only large font
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\section{Hello}
\blindtext[5]
\subsection{Hello 1.1}
\subsubsection{Hello1.1.1}
\blindtext[5]

\section{Road}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Road}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Road}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again Christian. Unfortunately now, I have to push up the word Content till the upper side of the frame. Moreover, I) would like that the main number 1,2--10 are in bold font.I have a problem for visualizing the bibliography. I wrote the bibliography in this way \begin{thebibliography}{99} and it is not reportet in the content.

Comment: @chrisis: You did not wrote that the main number should be bold, as well as there's no indication in your post that you want to have the `bib` section in the ToC. Of course, I did not address this