# How to move the word Content on the top of the page

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I have two problems. 
1.I would like to move the word Content on the top of the page. The word content is the table of content.
2. The second problem is regarding the space between each paragraph content.
   Now the number of subsection in the table of content sticks together with the title of the main section. How to separete them?[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=238mm, left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{5 pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{20 pt}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\bfseries\Large} % Only large font
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% titles in bold
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% page numbers in bold
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}% dot leaders in bold

\begin{document}


\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\tableofcontents 

\newpage

\section{bla bla}
...
\subsection{bla bla}
\subsubsection{bla bla}

\section{bla bla}
\subsection{bla bla}
\subsubsection{bla bla}



\medskip


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: One should typically ask *single* questions. To that end, one issue is addressed here: [How to move the chapter title upwards on page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309920/5764); [Space before chapters and contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39988/5764); [Change the vertical spacing above unnumbered sections headings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62068/5764)

Comment: This the basically the same question as this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311573/how-eliminate-a-blank-page-after-table-of-contents